# Accessing the DOM of a QtWebKit Application

Tags: python, qt, dom, functional-testing, qtwebkit

I have a Windows application, whose User Interface was done in QtWebKit.

So, I have an .exe with the QtWebKit container. Since I have to do automated GUI testing on it, I need to find a way to develop an API (or a WebDriver) in Python to interact with it.

I have found several options to do so, like Froglogic Squish, Smartbear, but they are out of my budget.

Some of the options I found so far are:

1. I heard Selenium automates web browsers. But I haven't found a way for it to interact with an application. Is it possible to adapt it?
2. I think it may be possible to run my application (in a QProcess for example), then "convert" it to a QtWebKit subclass and then interact with it with Signals and Slots (Or, just open it as a QtWebKit class). 
   Here is some information about Signal and Slots: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html
3. Does anybody know how does Squish work? I know that you give Squish the application, and Squish interacts with it, but I don't know how it does it.

I'm working on Python and PyQt4.